# Адаптация под мобильное устройство. html

Tags: html, адаптивная-верстка

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно нижеприведенный код html адаптировать под мобильное устройство,что нужно добавить или сделать?
Там таблица и в мобильной версии она на все экран идет с прокруткой.
Я новичок в этом.

```
<style>
    /* Стили таблицы (IKSWEB) */
    table.iksweb{text-decoration: none;border-collapse:collapse;width:auto;text-align:center;}
    table.iksweb th{font-weight:500;font-size:20px; color:#ffffff;background-color:#0f4c81;}
    table.iksweb td{font-size:20px;color:#0f4c81;}
    table.iksweb td,table.iksweb th{white-space:pre-wrap;padding:25px 38px;line-height:20px;vertical-align: middle;border: 1px solid #0f4c81;}  table.iksweb tr:hover{background-color:#f9fafb}
    table.iksweb tr:hover td{color:#354251;cursor:default;}
    .mobile-table{width: 400%; max-width: 400%; overflow-y: auto;}
</style>
<div class="mobile-table">
<table class="iksweb">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>название</th>
    <th>название</th>
    <th>название</th>
    <th>название</th>
    <th>название</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать правило @media для применением разных стилей в зависимости от ширины и высоты странице. Используется это правило очень легко  [тут можно прочитать побробную информацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

---

В интернете вы можете найти ширину для разных устройств, например 320px-480px для мобильного телефона, 480px - 768px для планшета и т.д.
Надеюсь помог

---

P.S: Данный пример работает когда ширина страницы меньше 600px, вы также можете изменить max-width на min-width и оно будет работать когда ширина страницы больше 600px

```css
.test {
  color: green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .test {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">lorem ipsim</div>
```

Comment: @Ина вам это помогло?)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно продумать как эта таблица должна выглядеть при адаптивности, далее:
Вы в css пишете правило @media(max-width: 480px) где max-width: это размер не более,
можете указать диапазон : к примеру : @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 540px), где min-width: читается как от
И все эти првила будут действовать в рамках этих размеров устройств